# Black spot void when using raster as tileset in mapbox studio

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

While trying to use raster tileset on globe in Mapbox Studio I got black spot on the top and bottom of globe which is not part of the raster. Raster extent is [-180,180,-85,85].
Any idea anyone how to get rid of this black spot?
[image]